# updating core data uitableview Xcode

Tags: core-data, xcode7, uitableview

I have an app that I am using core data to populate the text label in my cells for a uitableview.
It is an app that uses a user name and password to populate the cells.  by matching the user name and the password and the information shown in the cell (games won and lost) I can tell if the user cell should be a new one or update an cell that already exists.  This is working to a point.  I can create a new cell if there is no record of any score connected to that user name and password and if there is a record than the user name and password are linked to a specific index in the tableview.  When a new score is recorded it is added as a new cell if it is a new opponent or the old cell is updated if the user is already in the system.
The problem is that although the info in the cell text label is updated if I close the app and then reopen it only the original cell information is there not the updated information.  Here is some pertinent code
this is how I find out if there is an existing user what index they are at

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory11 = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *slasha = [documentsDirectory11 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Names"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:slasha]){
        count = 0;
    }
    else {
    NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:slasha error:nil];




    for (count = 0; count < (int)[directoryContents count]; count++)
    { NSLog(@"File %d: %@", (count + 1), [directoryContents objectAtIndex:count]);
    } NSLog(@"count:%d,",count);
    Names = [NSArray arrayWithArray:directoryContents];
    NSLog(@"namesArray;%@",Names);
    if (count == 0) {
    }
    else if (count == 1) {
        NSString *nameOne = [Names objectAtIndex:0];

        NSArray *coorArray = [nameOne componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
       firstStringa = [coorArray objectAtIndex:0];
        secondStringa = [coorArray objectAtIndex:1];
        if ([fileName2 isEqualToString:firstStringa] && [yourName isEqualToString:secondStringa]) {
            indexNumber = 0;
        }}
```

this is where I find out if they are a new user and save their info to a new cell and update the cell if they are a old user

```
if ([winsinChess isEqualToString:@"0"] && [winsinBack isEqualToString:@"0"] &&[winsinBattle isEqualToString:@"0"] && [winsinMankala isEqualToString:@"0"] && [winsinCapture isEqualToString:@"0"] && [winsinPente isEqualToString:@"0"] && [winsinLink isEqualToString:@"0"] &&  [losesinChess isEqualToString:@"0"] && [losesinBack isEqualToString:@"0"] && [losesinBattle isEqualToString:@"0"] && [losesinMankala isEqualToString:@"0"] && [losesinCapture isEqualToString:@"0"] && [losesinPente isEqualToString:@"0"] && [losesinLink isEqualToString:@"0"] && scoreOne == 0 && scoreTwo == 0) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        // Create a new managed object
        NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cell" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newDevice setValue:yourName forKey:@"name"];

        [newDevice setValue:Seven forKey:@"winloss"];

        NSError *error7 = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error7, [error7 localizedDescription]);
        }

    }
    else {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.tableDataMainView objectAtIndex:indexNumber ];
        [selectedDevice setValue:yourName forKey:@"name"];

        [selectedDevice setValue:Seven forKey:@"winloss"];
        NSError *error7 = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error7, [error7 localizedDescription]);
        }
               }
```

like i said a new user cell is added if appropriate and an old user's cell is updated repeatedly as long as the app is open in foreground or background but when the app is closed and reopened only the original cell info is shown.  I must not be saving the updated info correctly.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From your final summary of the problem, it sounds like you are saving a child context, but not the ultimate parent context which saves to the store.  Show how your Context (and the rest of the stack) is defined.

Answer (score 0):

so I figured this out I didn't dealoc my tableview array in my tableviewcontroller.  now it works fine.